# Disabling the Trace/Track methods in ibm websphere

Tags: logging, websphere

How i can disable Trace/Track methods in IBM WebSphere?

Comment: Can you elaborate on track? As mentioned below by trikelef, you can configure the tracing levels using the console. By default, the trace level is *=info which is recommended for prod environments. If you want detailed information only then do you need to do some extra work otherwise this is good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to just set trace level to `*=info`.

This is done by going to **Logging and Tracing** > **server_name** > **Diagnostic Trace Service** > **Change Log Detail Levels** > Select the "Configuration" Tab and set log level detail to `*=info` and apply.

If you need instant change of log level detail you should set the same value in the respective "Runtime" Tab field.

Comment: Is there any way to change the logging level  without going to the WAS admin console in Websphere 9?

Answer (score 1):

In WAS Console >> Troubleshooting >> Logging and Tracing >> Your ServerName > Diagnostic trace service >> Additional Properties >> *=info

Apply and Save.

Restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean HTTP Methods? Like GET, POST, etc?

If so you can use IHS to disable the incoming request:

Disabling the HTTP TRACE method
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/http_trace.html

On WebSphere itself, that is not possible since the Servlet specification requires that any Java EE compliant web container accept HTTP protocol